# How to force QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry to return updated geometry values

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QT application, which changes at startup the screen resolution (either via xrandr in unix or via CGConfigureDisplayMode on OSX)

Once the screen resolution change is done and successful, the application continues.

It then uses `QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(int)` to retrieve the size of the various screens.

The issue is that `QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry()` returns the dimensions *before* the resolution change occurred.

At this stage, the Qt event loop hasn't been started yet.

I will of course, once the Qt event loop is running receive the `QDesktopWidget::resized(int)` signal, and calling `QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry` will then returns the updated dimensions. But by then it's too late.

I could force a refresh of the screen once the signal is received, and recalculate everything, but that gives an ugly effect as you see the window being displayed with the wrong dimension first, and then using the right ones.

So the question is:

how do you make sure `QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry()` returns the actual values, rather than the one at the times the application started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually you could implement your desktop resolution switch in main.cpp (int main()) before creating your MainWindow. If this is possible you could switch and your window will have the right dimension. You probably could run a short custom eventloop there also.

As last resort split your application in 2 processes. The first will set up screen resolution and also will be hidden. As soon as resolution switch was sucessfull, your application will call the real app starting in correct dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is any choice other than to wait until the Qt event-loop has started and receive the signal.  You could avoid the ugly effect by keep your window hidden until after the signal has been received.

Comment: To make things worse, it appears that with Qt 4.8.5 and Maverick, screen change signal aren't being sent.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended doing, right after the resolution change:

```
QEventLoop loop;
QTimer timer;
QDesktopWidget *desktop = QApplication::desktop();

timer.setSingleShot(true);
QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),
                 &loop, SLOT(quit()));
QObject::connect(desktop, SIGNAL(resized(int)),
                 &loop, SLOT(quit()));
QObject::connect(desktop, SIGNAL(workAreaResized(int)),
                 &loop, SLOT(quit()));
timer.start(300); //300ms maximum wait
loop.exec();
```

this short wait, is just enough for the Qt framework to process the resolution change, and the next call to `QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry()` will return the expect values